# How to make label inside div to be in the same position as lower ones

Tags: css, html

I have a problem. I have a code:

```
<div><label>Comments:</label>0</div>
<div><label>Author:</label>AuthorName</div>
<div><label>Rating</label>5/5</div>
```

How can I make it to be in the same width to look aesthetic? I tried to change .css label to specific width and float div to the left but it didn't work. Can somebody help me?

I would love to put it into a table with td's with the same width but I cannot change what I have in divs... Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I find this solution tends to work better than float.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had label display set to display: inline; It didn't work then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    div {
        width: 300px;
        text-align:left;
    }
    label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 5px;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```